# How to load dynamically a class with class.forName in JBOSS 7

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I'm migrating my web application to `JBOSS 7` and I have problems with the `Class.forName` method.

I have basically 2 jars, each one in one different module:

- CampusComponentsJava-1.4.4.jar
- CampusGateway-2.5.3-SNAPSHOT.jar

The code from CampusComponentsJava loads dynamically a class from CampusGateway-2.5.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
in the following way:

```
Class.forName("edu.uoc.campusgateway.osid.authentication.AuthenticationManager")
```

I have created 2 modules in the modules folder:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="edu.uoc.oki2">

     <resources>

    <resource-root path="CampusGateway-2.5.3-SNAPSHOT.jar" />
    <resource-root path="CampusLauncherJava-1.1.3-SNAPSHOT-filter.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="OkiBusJava-1.2.2-config-uoc.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="OkiBusXmlSchemas-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="OkiOSID-2.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="JavaUtils-1.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="LibTecsidel.jar"/>

    </resources>

    <dependencies>

    </dependencies>
   </module>
```

And

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="edu.uoc.okicomps">

   <resources>
     <resource-root path="CampusComponentsJava-1.4.4.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="CampusComponentsJava-1.4.4-config-uoc.jar"/>

    </resources>

    <dependencies>
       <module name="edu.uoc.oki2" export="true"/>
    </dependencies>
 </module>
```

I the later one the  tag to express the idea that module edu.uoc.okicomps depends on module edu.uoc.oki2 since one jar of the edu.uoc.okicomps module wants to load dynamically a class from one jar of the module edu.uoc.oki2:

Finally, since the webapp needs all the jars I have declared explicitally access to both modules of the webapp in the  META-INF/MANIFEST.xml

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Class-Path: 
 Dependencies: edu.uoc.okicomps,edu.uoc.oki2
```

However it is not working failing with the exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class edu.uoc.campusgateway.osid.authentication.AuthenticationManager
```

Any help would be apreciated!

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The problem was that the Class.forName, due to its own nature, executes static code and the constructor.

In this case, the static code tries to load through the classloader a property file that is included in another jar that I forgot to add. So the fix to my problem is:

1) add the following line to the module.xml

2) add physically the file CampusComponentsJava-1.4.4-config-uoc.jar to the 
    modules\edu\uoc\oki2\main folder